# Some kind of "tearing"?

Tags: tearing

Yesterday I experienced some kind of tearing on my rather new install of Ubuntu 14.04. Still, I've done some tweaking using the tweak-tool.

Well, yesterday some program was reported crashing, shortly before this weird tearing appeared for the first time. But now it happens again and again, especially when I use the startup disk creator to erase my pendrive before creating the startup disk.

I don't know what it is, but maybe you guys can help me out.

Currently, I haven't installed any drivers that aren't installed out of the box.

[image: http://s1.directupload.net/images/140908/6lso78cp.png]

Comment: Try going to additional drivers and seeing if there are any drivers for the system, can you also paste the specifications of your computer/graphics card.

Comment: try to run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` in terminal (<Ctrl>+<Alt>+<T>)

Comment: Yeah, additional driver's-GUI shows me some available drivers for my NVIDIA GTX660. My CPU is an i5-3470 and I've got 8 gb RAM.

If it helps (paste of my complete system-info): http://pastebin.com/kQjb73Wh

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a new user account

```
sudo adduser myname
```

Then logout, and login into the new user account. Many Compiz/user interface problem was solved by this simple solution.